# TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstname' of null (react js redux firebase)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[Error Cannot Read Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCIBc.png)

Why can't I get the properties in my collection like firstname? This code is react js and firebase. I'm just a newbie in react js can someone help me to solve this problem?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { firestoreConnect } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import { compose } from 'redux';
function ThankYou(props) {
  console.log(props);
  const { student } = props;
  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <h1>Congratulations!!</h1>
          //I cant get the student firstname
          <h5>{student.firstname}you have been succesfully Pre-enrolled</h5>
          <p>
            To be fully enrolled please contact or visit SAINT ANTHONY ACADEMY 
            to be fully enrolled
          </p>
          <hr />
          <h5>This is your Reference Code: </h5>
          <h1>{props.match.params.id}</h1>
          <hr />
          <p>Show your code to the admin to be fully enrolled</p>
          <p>
            <strong>Save this Reference code for verification</strong>
          </p>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const students = state.firestore.data.students;
  console.log(students);
  const student = students ? students : null;
  return {
    student: student,
  };
};

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  firestoreConnect(props => [
    {
      collection: 'students',
      limit: 1,
      where: [['lrn', '==', props.match.params.id]],
    },
  ]),
)(ThankYou);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are doing  const student = students ? students:null; . whilie it fetches the data from the firebase it sets the student to null. can you tell what are you getting when are you doing just console.log(student) .

you can try this

{student && student.firstname}you have been succesfully Pre-enrolled

Answer (score 0):

**i think conponent rendring before data comes **
const students=state.firestore.data ? state.firestore.data.students " void 0 or null
   console.log(students)